# Spark submit exit in yarn-cluster with -1000

Tags: deployment, apache-spark

When I submit jars in local mode it works fine but, in yarn cluster it fails with below error,

```
    spark-submit --class com.ffx.events.logevents.LogParser --master yarn-cluster
    --jars hdfs://EC22.internal:8020/user/hadoop/dir/src/guava-18.0.jar
    --driver-class-path logevents-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar,hdfs:/
    /EC22.internal:8020/user/hadoop/dir/src/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar hdfs://e
    c2ipaddress.internal:8020/user/hadoop/dir/src/logevents-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with
    -dependencies.jar.filepart -input /from-s3-1year/ffx-data/20151001/* -output 
    hdfs://EC22.internal:8020/user/hadoop/dir/output/20151120
```

Error trace part of it,

```
15/11/20 14:00:00 INFO Client: Application report for application_1447788091680_0045 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/11/20 14:00:01 INFO Client: Application report for application_1447788091680_0045 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/11/20 14:00:02 INFO Client: Application report for application_1447788091680_0045 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/11/20 14:00:03 INFO Client: Application report for application_1447788091680_0045 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/11/20 14:00:04 INFO Client: Application report for application_1447788091680_0045 (state: FAILED)
15/11/20 14:00:04 INFO Client:
         client token: N/A
         diagnostics: Application application_1447788091680_0045 failed 2 times due to AM Container for 
                                        appattempt_1447788091680_0045_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://EC22.internal:20888/proxy/
                                        application_1447788091680_0045/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: File does not exist: hdfs://EC22.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/
                                        application_1447788091680_0045/__spark_conf__7360399142592952913.zip
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://EC22.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/
                                        application_1447788091680_0045/__spark_conf__7360399142592952913.zip
```

I'm not familiar with spark. Appreciate some help

Comment: Let me know if for other details thanks!

Comment: do you have access to the yarn container logs on the executors? They can be found in the directory `yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs`